# Hold key and select accented characters (accented character popup) does not work in Terminal

Tags: terminal, keyboard, iterm

When I'm in an application such as Firefox, Textedit, BBEdit, Pages etc. - virtually any application which provides something like a text entry field -, I find the following feature at work:

When I press a vocal letter (say `i` for a second or so, a small window pops up where I can choose between various accented versions of this character. In the case of `i`, the list contains `î`, `ï`, `í`, `ī` and `ì`, and typing a number from 1 to 5 selects which of those characters I want to actually enter. When I press an interpunction character (say `-` or `.`) and hold it, automatic key repeat starts (`--------------........`). This is reasonable and handy.

Interestingly, `Terminal.app` (and also `iTerm2.app`) behave differntly, in that they **always** do an automatic key repeat. Pressing and holding  the `i` does give me the aforementined option, but always starts to produce a string of `i` character: `iiiiiiii`.

Is there a possibility to enable the terminal applications to react in the same way as those Mac programs using a GUI, when a key is pressed an held for some period? I guess that this behaviour is done inside the keyboard driver, and therefore configurable by the application which requests keyboard entry.

I am aware that I can enter some of these characters using a dead key - for instance typing `´` and `i` produces `í`, but there is no way I could use with this approach a `ī` or a `ï` (I use the Austrian German input source).

Comment: Dead keys can be used to make everything if you will activate the input source called ABC Extended.

Comment: @TomGewecke: I'm not talking about dead keys. How would you produce a character such as `æ` or `ō` or `ï`m using dead keys? Basically I just would use the facility which seems to be active in any other application except the two terminal applications (at least I have **not found yet** another application, where the _accented character popup_  would not appear) in my terminal as well.

Comment: With ABC Extended, æ is option ', ö is option u then o, ī is option a then i.  Press and Hold will always have llmited choices compared to dead keys.  For full info see https://sites.psu.edu/symbolcodes/mac/codemacext/

Comment: The press and hold feature is not controlled by the keyboard driver, but by system/library/input methods/PressAndHold.app

Comment: @TomGewecke : I didn't mean `ö`, I meant `ō`.  Option + `i` together gives me `⁄`. option + `'` just produces a `’`. I guess the differences are related to the keyboard layout: I have a German keyboard and the keyboard settings are "AT" (Austrian). But thanks anyway for the link. My preference for the popup solution is that I don't have to remember key combinations: I see whith once glance what is available and can pick from the list. From your information about the PressAndHold.app, I guess I would have to file a change request for iTerm2...

Comment: If you would switch to the German Standard input source, the dead keys can do much more than with AT.  Option i then o gives you ō.  To see everything, use the keyboard viewer.   https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/use-the-keyboard-viewer-on-mac-mchlp1015/13.0/mac/13.0

Comment: @TomGewecke : Not for me. Option + i gives me `⁄` like for the AT-Keyboard setting. Option + o gives me `ø`, which is admittedly nice, but different from `ō`. The keyboard viewer does not show me any `ō` or `ī` or `ū`, no matter which dead key I press with it. BTW, the æ you mentioned before can be produced by option + ä. It seems that just the characters with an overbar (horizontal line on top) can't be created using dead keys.

Comment: @TomGewecke: I just noticed, that I missed one point in your comment: You recommended turning on _ABC Extended_. I was not aware, that a separate configuration step is necessary for this, and didn't do this - my bad! Right now, my input source menu in the status bar only shows DE (respectively AT), Romaji, Hiragana and Katakana, but no ABC Extended. I will have to read about the consequences of this input source, and try it out tomorrow.

Comment: You did not turn on German Standard , which is different from plain German.  You need to take a look at the input source settings and add that one, in addition to ABC Extended if you want it.  The latter is of course qwerty instead of qwertz.  How to add keyboards is at  https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/write-in-another-language-on-mac-mchlp1406/14.0/mac/14.0

Comment: @TomGewecke: I found "German Standard" (don't know the difference to just German). I did see "ABC Extended", but this is only for the "English" keyboard input source, which does not make much sense with German keyboard having the qwertz layout annotaged, so I did not turn it on. I also automatically got - without explicitly requesting it - an additional menu entry saying "ABC - QWERTZ'. Don't know what is this for. None of the new entries would get me an ō when doing option+o.

Comment: ABC qwertz is for someone who wants to use a qwertz layou but does not want to look at a partricular country's name when doing so.  As said before, when you have German Standard active, you get ō via option i, then o (not via option o).  Use the Keyboard Viewer (instruction link also given earlier) to see how keyboards differ.  ABC Extended can be used to write any Latin-script language, not just English, as long as you can handle a qwerty layout.

Comment: @TomGewecke : Got it, and can reproduce it. However, with German Standard, producing a `@` does not work anymore in the "usual" way: In the Austrian or German layout, I pressed option + l to get a @. In the German Standard layout, this combination produces the intresting character `˛`. To produce a `@` there, I have to type option+q. From a view user's point of view, this is counteractive, since the key `L` on the keyboard is labelled with a small `@` next to it, so that we remember where to find this character.

Comment: @TomGewecke : At least thanks to your patient explanations, I understand now a lot more how to use the various keyboard layouts to get a the characters I want and I can choose what works best for me. For conevenience, and the texts I am typing, I still find the _accented character popup_ hard to beat, and I have created a feature request for iTerm2 at github, asking that they offer the PressAndHold approach as an option.